# React Native, I can't tap without closing keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

[Here is my phone screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiOxU.png) I tried ScrollView with keyboardShouldPersistTaps, but it didn't work. I have a ScrollView for Autocomplete suggestions, and when user can types there, they should also be able to select from suggestions. However, without closing keyboard, it is not possible in my case. Here is my work

```
       <ScrollView
              scrollEnabled={false}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>

            <View style={{ maxHeight: 220 }}>
                 <ScrollView style={Style.suggestionContainer}
                      scrollEnabled={true} >        

                       {this.state.showOptions.map(this.renderSuggestions)}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
      </ScrollView>
         .
         .
         .


       private renderSuggestions(option: MultiInputQuestionOption) {
            return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addSelection.bind(this, option)} >
                <Text style={Style.suggestions}>
                    {option[this.props.titleKey]}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity >
           )
      }
```

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: why do you have two scrollview components? try it with just one

Comment: Any luck with this bug?

Answer (score 12):

You need to pass the key `keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’` on scroll view which contains the TextInput:-

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’>
   ...
   <TextInput />
</ScrollView>
```

And if you are having issue inside of a modal then You need to pass key `keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’` on `All` scrollview which are in component stack for the screen. In the ancestors/parent of the Modal also.

Like in my case:

```
const CountryModal=(props)=>{
 return(
   <Modal
     visible={props.visible}
     transparent={false}
     {...props}
   >
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’>  
      …
    </ScrollView>
   />
  )
 }
```

In Parent class:
In the parent class where ancestors of modal is there. You need to pass key keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’`.

```
class Parent extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’> // pass ‘handled’ here also
      …
     <CountryModal />  // Its the same modal being used as a component in parent class.
    </ScrollView>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding
`keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}`
to the second ScrollView as well.

Comment: Can you upload a screen shot so i take a better look at what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: I edited my question and added the screenshot there. I have a autocomplete component. In my core screen, there is a button on the top. If you press that button, a Modal opens and you see that screen. In modal, you can write in the TextInput component. After some typing, you can see and  choose a suggestion below the Text Input.
I want to choose suggestion without dismissing keyboard. Keyboard should stay there when I tap TouchableOpacitied text.

Comment: hmmm why do u have a scroll view if the scrollEnable is false?

Comment: Did u try to replace the outer ScrollView with a regular view?

Comment: try pushing ur code to a repository so i can help u out.

Comment: don't set this to true anymore.  set it to "always"

Answer (score 1):

In My case I have Scrollview inside Flatlist so I have to add

> keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'} In Flatlist.

```
<FlatList
       horizontal
       scrollEnabled={false} 
       keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
               <ScrollView
                      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
               </ScrollView>    
 </FlatList>
```

And Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `'handled'` value for `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property because the `true` value is deprecated. use the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` in two `ScrollView`s and handle your keyboard state in somewhere else by using `Keyboard.dismiss()` function.